MIPS pipelined CPU Read and Write from Registers on First and Second Halves of Clock Cycle
In a pipelined MIPS CPU, writing to the pipeline registers, registers and PC occurs when the in the rising edge of the clock, and reading occurs in the falling edge, according to my understanding.
Therefore, my questions are:

When an instruction reaches the EX stage, does that mean it has to wait to the falling edge to read from the pipeline registers and execute the instruction?

Do we have to wait for the falling edge to read from PC and the registers?

In WB, it has to wait for the falling edge to read from the pipeline registers, but it also has to wait for the rising edge to write to the register file, so how does this stage only take one clock cycle?



Our normal guideline is to please ask only one question per post.  If you have multiple questions, they can be posted separately.

(Waiting for edges is an odd notion. Clock edges got to be late enough one particular implementation problem (metastability) does not intolerably impact reliability. A (significant) change in clock signal allows outputs of storage components to change value according to inputs.)
